SonarCloud getting different faied requests when integration with Azure Devops
I am using SonarCloud with AzureDevops and from some pipelines
It works fine sometimes but sometimes I am getting errors like:
Prepare errors
2024-08-19T15:35:15.7216142Z ##[section]Starting: Prepare SonarCloud Analysys
2024-08-19T15:35:15.7219727Z ==============================================================================
2024-08-19T15:35:15.7219806Z Task         : Prepare Analysis Configuration
2024-08-19T15:35:15.7219851Z Description  : Prepare SonarCloud analysis configuration
2024-08-19T15:35:15.7219901Z Version      : 2.3.2
2024-08-19T15:35:15.7219947Z Author       : sonarsource
2024-08-19T15:35:15.7220004Z Help         : [More Information](https://docs.sonarcloud.io/advanced-setup/ci-based-analysis/sonarcloud-extension-for-azure-devops/)
2024-08-19T15:35:15.7220081Z ==============================================================================
2024-08-19T15:35:25.7666382Z ##[warning]Error while executing SonarCloud:Prepare task: [SQ] API GET '/api/server/version' failed, error is request to https://sonarcloud.io/api/server/version failed, reason: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
2024-08-19T15:35:25.7673499Z ##[error][SQ] API GET '/api/server/version' failed, error is request to https://sonarcloud.io/api/server/version failed, reason: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
2024-08-19T15:35:25.7675309Z ##[section]Finishing: Prepare SonarCloud Analysys

Analyze Errors:
2024-08-19T11:20:47.7107020Z 13:20:47.710 DEBUG: --> GET https://sonarcloud.io/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt,updatedAt,deprecatedKeys&activation=true&qprofile=AYpgWsLdEvuW0b7359Tt&ps=500&p=1
2024-08-19T11:20:48.1233067Z 13:20:48.122 DEBUG: <-- 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt,updatedAt,deprecatedKeys&activation=true&qprofile=AYpgWsLdEvuW0b7359Tt&ps=500&p=1 (412ms, unknown-length body)
2024-08-19T11:20:49.4631927Z 13:20:49.462 DEBUG: --> GET https://sonarcloud.io/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt,updatedAt,deprecatedKeys&activation=true&qprofile=AYpffK8n04WetOkF8d2u&ps=500&p=1
2024-08-19T11:20:49.6015215Z 13:20:49.600 DEBUG: <-- 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt,updatedAt,deprecatedKeys&activation=true&qprofile=AYpffK8n04WetOkF8d2u&ps=500&p=1 (136ms, unknown-length body)
2024-08-19T11:20:49.9905183Z 13:20:49.989 DEBUG: --> GET https://sonarcloud.io/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt,updatedAt,deprecatedKeys&activation=true&qprofile=AYpffK8n04WetOkF8d3I&ps=500&p=1
2024-08-19T11:20:50.7814293Z 13:20:50.780 DEBUG: --> GET https://sonarcloud.io/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt,updatedAt,deprecatedKeys&activation=true&qprofile=AYpffK8n04WetOkF8d3B&ps=500&p=1
2024-08-19T11:21:50.7969168Z 13:21:50.783 DEBUG: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
2024-08-19T11:21:50.7973371Z 13:21:50.790 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2024-08-19T11:21:50.7976971Z 13:21:50.790 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8224439Z 13:21:50.820 DEBUG: Cleanup org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS$FileStoreAttributes$$Lambda$288/0x00007f874c2fa898@44de94c3 during JVM shutdown
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8249394Z ##[error]13:21:50.816 ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.report.ActiveRulesPublisher
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:52)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:621)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.getArrayInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:334)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.access$100(CollectionComponentParameter.java:49)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:139)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:141)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.instantiateComponentAsIsStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1034)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.addAdapterIfStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1026)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1003)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:109)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart(GlobalContainer.java:128)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:123)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:109)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:58)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:52)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:126)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:81)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:62)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.api.batch.rule.internal.DefaultActiveRules
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:52)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:50)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to request https://sonarcloud.io/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt,updatedAt,deprecatedKeys&activation=true&qprofile=AYpffK8n04WetOkF8d3B&ps=500&p=1
    at com.sonarsource.scanner.engine.webapi.client.HttpConnector.doCall(HttpConnector.java:229)
    at com.sonarsource.scanner.engine.webapi.client.HttpConnector.get(HttpConnector.java:136)
    at com.sonarsource.scanner.engine.webapi.client.HttpConnector.call(HttpConnector.java:120)
    at org.sonar.scanner.http.DefaultScannerWsClient.call(DefaultScannerWsClient.java:54)
    at org.sonar.scanner.rule.DefaultActiveRulesLoader.load(DefaultActiveRulesLoader.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.rule.ActiveRulesProvider.load(ActiveRulesProvider.java:109)
    at org.sonar.scanner.rule.ActiveRulesProvider.load(ActiveRulesProvider.java:68)
    at org.sonar.scanner.rule.ActiveRulesProvider.provide(ActiveRulesProvider.java:54)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.invokeMethod(MethodInjector.java:129)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.access$000(MethodInjector.java:39)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:113)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:50)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.newTimeoutException(Http2Stream.kt:675)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.exitAndThrowIfTimedOut(Http2Stream.kt:684)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeHeaders(Http2Stream.kt:143)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http2ExchangeCodec.kt:97)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:110)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at com.sonarsource.scanner.engine.webapi.client.OkHttpClientBuilder.addHeaders(OkHttpClientBuilder.java:230)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.kt:221)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:154)
    at com.sonarsource.scanner.engine.webapi.client.HttpConnector.doCall(HttpConnector.java:227)
    ... 72 more
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8256220Z 13:21:50.816 ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8256809Z java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.report.ActiveRulesPublisher
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8257042Z    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:52)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8257222Z    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:621)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8257453Z    at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.getArrayInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:334)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8257646Z    at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.access$100(CollectionComponentParameter.java:49)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8259341Z    at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:139)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8259543Z    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:141)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8259947Z    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8260490Z    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8260690Z    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8260880Z    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8261069Z    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8261256Z    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8261459Z    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8261631Z    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8261807Z    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.instantiateComponentAsIsStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1034)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8261995Z    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.addAdapterIfStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1026)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8262172Z    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1003)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8262338Z    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8262507Z    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:122)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8262677Z    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:109)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8262832Z    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart(GlobalContainer.java:128)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8263188Z    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:123)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8263373Z    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:109)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8263536Z    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:58)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8263685Z    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:52)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8263853Z    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8264021Z    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8264185Z    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8264374Z    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8264533Z    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8264700Z    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8264854Z    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8265005Z    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8265170Z    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8265377Z    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:126)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8265535Z    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:81)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8265686Z    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:62)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8265839Z Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.api.batch.rule.internal.DefaultActiveRules
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8266123Z    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:52)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8266329Z    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8266497Z    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8266752Z    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8267028Z    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8267227Z    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8267412Z    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8267585Z    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8267775Z    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8267972Z    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8268164Z    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8268329Z    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8268492Z    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8268661Z    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8268844Z    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:50)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8268988Z    ... 36 more
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8269171Z Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to request https://sonarcloud.io/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt,updatedAt,deprecatedKeys&activation=true&qprofile=AYpffK8n04WetOkF8d3B&ps=500&p=1
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8269562Z    at com.sonarsource.scanner.engine.webapi.client.HttpConnector.doCall(HttpConnector.java:229)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8269743Z    at com.sonarsource.scanner.engine.webapi.client.HttpConnector.get(HttpConnector.java:136)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8269908Z    at com.sonarsource.scanner.engine.webapi.client.HttpConnector.call(HttpConnector.java:120)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8270081Z    at org.sonar.scanner.http.DefaultScannerWsClient.call(DefaultScannerWsClient.java:54)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8270250Z    at org.sonar.scanner.rule.DefaultActiveRulesLoader.load(DefaultActiveRulesLoader.java:48)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8270419Z    at org.sonar.scanner.rule.ActiveRulesProvider.load(ActiveRulesProvider.java:109)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8270582Z    at org.sonar.scanner.rule.ActiveRulesProvider.load(ActiveRulesProvider.java:68)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8270753Z    at org.sonar.scanner.rule.ActiveRulesProvider.provide(ActiveRulesProvider.java:54)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8270910Z    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8271072Z    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8271263Z    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8271420Z    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8271581Z    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.invokeMethod(MethodInjector.java:129)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8271752Z    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.access$000(MethodInjector.java:39)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8271916Z    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:113)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8272103Z    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8272297Z    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8272483Z    at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8272658Z    at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8272927Z    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8273088Z    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8273321Z    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8273523Z    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:50)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8273672Z    ... 50 more
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8273781Z Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8273938Z    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.newTimeoutException(Http2Stream.kt:675)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8274118Z    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.exitAndThrowIfTimedOut(Http2Stream.kt:684)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8274282Z    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeHeaders(Http2Stream.kt:143)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8274455Z    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http2ExchangeCodec.kt:97)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8274685Z    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:110)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8274852Z    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:93)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8275016Z    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
2024-08-19T11:21:50.8275193Z    at 

Publish Errors
2024-08-16T14:39:05.7187626Z ##[section]Starting: Publish SonarCloud Quality Gate Results
2024-08-16T14:39:05.7190690Z ==============================================================================
2024-08-16T14:39:05.7190758Z Task         : Publish Quality Gate Result
2024-08-16T14:39:05.7190803Z Description  : Publish SonarCloud's Quality Gate result on the Azure Pipelines build result. To be used after the actual analysis.
2024-08-16T14:39:05.7190891Z Version      : 1.16.1
2024-08-16T14:39:05.7190925Z Author       : sonarsource
2024-08-16T14:39:05.7190963Z Help         : [More Information](https://docs.sonarcloud.io/advanced-setup/ci-based-analysis/sonarcloud-extension-for-azure-devops/)
2024-08-16T14:39:05.7191050Z ==============================================================================
2024-08-16T14:39:05.9500412Z ##[warning]This task is deprecated. Please upgrade to the latest version. For more information, refer to https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarcloud/advanced-setup/ci-based-analysis/sonarcloud-extension-for-azure-devops/
2024-08-16T14:39:16.7410568Z ##[error]Error retrieving analysis: [SQ] API GET '/api/qualitygates/project_status' failed, error is request to https://sonarcloud.io/api/qualitygates/project_status?analysisId=... failed, reason: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
2024-08-16T14:39:16.7411363Z ##[warning]Error while executing SonarCloud:Publish task: Could not fetch analysis for ID '...'
2024-08-16T14:39:16.7411841Z ##[error]Could not fetch analysis for ID '...'
2024-08-16T14:39:16.7453622Z ##[section]Finishing: Publish SonarCloud Quality Gate Results

Tasks
- task: SonarCloudPrepare@2
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.runSonar }}', true))
  displayName: Prepare SonarCloud Analysys
  inputs:
    extraProperties: |
      sonar.analysis.buildId=$(Build.BuildId)
      sonar.analysis.buildTag=$(buildTag)
      sonar.analysis.repository=$(Build.Repository.ID)
      sonar.analysis.sha1=$(Build.SourceVersion)
      sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/testResults/coverage.opencover.xml
      sonar.exclusions=$(excludePaths)
      sonar.coverage.exclusions=$(excludeFromCoverage)
      sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
    SonarCloud: sonarcloud
    organization: $(sonarOrganization)
    projectKey: $(sonarProjectKey)
    projectName: $(sonarProjectName)
    scannerMode: 'MSBuild'

- task: SonarCloudAnalyze@2
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.runSonar }}', true))
  displayName: Analyze with SonarCloud

- task: SonarCloudPublish@2
  displayName: Publish SonarCloud Quality Gate Results
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.runSonar }}', true))
  inputs:
    pollingTimeoutSec: '300'


My current assomption is that our instance is under load and threfore not able to properly serve all requests

I am not sure where in sonarClould I can see the logs or any metrics

Do you mean these errors were intermittent issue or could be reproduced by specific version of code or agent environment? From the current logs, we could only see errors Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout or failed, reason: Client network socket disconnected. By the way, have you tried with the older version of those tasks like SonarCloudPrepare@1?

Yes the errors are intermittent same code base would go eventually true (if you retry a few times).
Agent is always the same.
I tried with v1 and v2 version of the tasks they had the same problems

Will try a different Agent to rule that out

If possible would you also have a test with MS-hosted agent? Is there any other issue message from Sonar Cloud as well?
